# Convert String to Int Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, int

Here i have some some form group with values from database

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputTotalBayar">Total Bayar</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTotalBayar" placeholder="Total Bayar" name="totalBayar" value="{{ $peminjaman->totalBayar }}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputJumlahBayar">Jumlah Bayar</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputJumlahBayar" onchange="" placeholder="Jumlah Bayar" name="jumlahBayar" value="{{ $peminjaman->jml_bayar }}">
</div>
```

Then i want to give new values in this form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputDenda">Denda</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputDenda" placeholder="Denda" name="denda" value="{{ $peminjaman->denda }}">
</div>
```

so, when i give new values in form group Denda, the output will be show in here

```
<p>Bayar Pengembalian: <div id="bayar" name="bayar"></div></p>
```

My code for javascript was like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var bayar = parseInt("0");
var totalBayar = parseInt($("#inputTotalBayar").val());
var jumlahBayar = parseInt($("#inputJumlahBayar").val());
var denda = parseInt($("#exampleInputDenda").val());    
$("#exampleInputDenda").change(function() {
    bayar = bayar + denda + totalBayar - jumlahBayar;        
    $("#bayar").html(bayar);
});
```

but the calculation result doesn't appear, can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I find that this shouldn't be ever asked in SO... a quick search on the net would be enough to determine how to perform type conversions........

Comment: Put your variable initialization inside your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
$("#exampleInputDenda").keyup(function() {
    var bayar = parseInt("0");
    var totalBayar = isNaN($("#inputTotalBayar").val()) ? 0 : parseInt($("#inputTotalBayar").val());
    var jumlahBayar = isNaN($("#inputJumlahBayar").val()) ? 0 : parseInt($("#inputJumlahBayar").val());
    var denda = isNaN($("#exampleInputDenda").val()) ? 0 : parseInt($("#exampleInputDenda").val());
    bayar = bayar + denda + totalBayar - jumlahBayar;  
    $("#bayar").html(bayar);
});
```

Error checking :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change you event handler so you can get the values when the actual event happen like so - [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/07vd5hh4/)

```
$("#exampleInputDenda").change(function() {
    var bayar = parseInt("0");
var totalBayar = parseInt($("#inputTotalBayar").val());
var jumlahBayar = parseInt($("#inputJumlahBayar").val());
var denda = parseInt($("#exampleInputDenda").val());  
    var res = bayar + denda + totalBayar - jumlahBayar;        
    $("#bayar").html(res);
});
```

P.S
Andd click `Enter` to actually see the new value!

Answer (score 0):

see this with slide change of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#exampleInputDenda").change(function(){
getValues();
});

// when using click event on button
   $("#me").click(function(){
        getValues();
    });

    });

function getValues(){
    var bayar = parseInt("0");
    var totalBayar = parseInt($("#inputTotalBayar").val());
    var jumlahBayar = parseInt($("#inputJumlahBayar").val());
    var denda = parseInt($("#exampleInputDenda").val());    

        bayar = bayar + denda + totalBayar - jumlahBayar;        
        $("#bayar").html(bayar);

}
</script>
```

to see on click use this:

```
<button id="me" onclick='getValues()'>Click me!</button>
```